# Перебор свойств вложенного объекта

Tags: xml, php

Всем привет.

Создаю xml файл со структурой

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parent>
<son>Tolya</son>

<big>Sash
......
<year>1999</year>
.....
<fu>
future
<date>dates</date>
</fu>
</big> 
</parent>
```

Теперь есть файл php

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file('info.xml');
```

Я хочу получить доступ к значению свойств объекта $xml.
Можно получить доступ к son ,но не знаю как **к year (может он вложен еще в пару элементов),если не известна структура файла**.
Помогите с функцией обхода всех свойств объекта.
Пробовал создать такую функцию для обхода всех элементов

```
function recurse($obj){

foreach($obj as $k=>$v){
    if(is_object($k)) {recurse($k);}
    else{
echo $k;
    }

}
}
recurse($xml);
```

но не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('info.xml');
foreach ($xml->parent as $val)
{
    echo $val->son.'<br>';
    echo $val->big->year.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: я не знаю где находиться Year.Может он вложен еще в пару элементов.Как тогда поступить?

Comment: Поищи функцию может быть есть  http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Либо через регулярное выражение!